# Centering 3 buttons within div on the page using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 3 buttons that I'm looking to keep central on the page, however as the window gets wider the buttons skew off from central (shown in image).

What would be the HTML/CSS to fix this so that they are always perfectly central?

It seems as if it is skewing more to the left, leaving extra space on the right.

[image: screenshot of issue]

```
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Creative Checker</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="text-center">
                            1. Select product type:
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <button type="button" id="btn-snapshot" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">Snapshot</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <button type="button" id="btn-tmd" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">TMD</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <button type="button" id="btn-bpush" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">Behavioural Push</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">                   
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p class="text-center">
                            2. Upload folder/images:
                        </p>
                        <form action="server.php"
                            class="dropzone"
                            id="my-awesome-dropzone"
                            onsubmit="onSubmit()">
                            <!-- <select name="product-type" id="product_type">
                                <option value="snapshot">
                                    Snapshot
                                </option>
                                <option value="TMD">                                
                                    TMD
                                </option>
                                <option value="b-push">
                                    Behavioural Push
                                </option>
                            </select> -->                       
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>  
        </div>
```

```
#btn-snapshot {
    z-index: 39;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 15px;
    background-color: #75ACE0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#btn-tmd {
    z-index: 39;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 15px;
    background-color: #75ACE0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#btn-bpush {
    z-index: 39;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 15px;
    background-color: #75ACE0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Is the html block you shared inside another column?

Comment: Can you please share your `CSS` code as well so we can get idea about it?

Comment: @Viral sorry, I've added the CSS too!

Comment: @adamjamesb, Try putting `text-align: center` to your column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class `text-center` to `col-lg-4` and the button will be centered.

If bootstrap is not available, add the following CSS code to your file.

```
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like this?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.btn {
  color: white;
  background: #45C9F8;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="button" id="btn-snapshot" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">Snapshot</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="button" id="btn-tmd" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">TMD</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="button" id="btn-bpush" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">Behavioural Push</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need `justify-content: center;`, instead of `space-between`.

Answer (score 0):

Purely from the information given at the moment I can only suggest ensuring that the `class row mb-3` is set at 100% width.

```
.row mb-3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

If this doesn't fix your issue, post your CSS code so we can see what styles you have applied. It'll make troubleshooting easier.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code: 
`<div class="container">`

`<div class="row">`

`<div class="col">`

```
` <button type="button" id="btn-snapshot" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">Snapshot</button>`
```

`</div>`

`<div class="col">`

```
 ` <button type="button" id="btn-tmd" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">TMD</button>`
```

`</div>`

```
`<div class="col">`

  `<button type="button" id="btn-bpush" class="btn btn-secondary col-lg-12">Behavioural Push</button>`
```

`</div>`

`</div>`

`</div>`

CSS:

`.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}`

`.col {
  border: solid 0px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}`

Here is a working bootstrap fiddle [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/Arpit09/903qs8j5/2/) for the same.